# forkJoin not passing status 401 as error in MEAN app

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack, fork-join

In my MEAN app, I'm using forkJoin in Angular 6 to make sequential calls to my server.

Whenever there is any error while requesting data, I'm passing status 401 along with an error object.

I'm subscribing to the requests, but the `error` function is not being triggered. Only `data` function is being triggered with the error object.

Here is my code:

**TS file Code**

```
forkJoin(
      this.http.post(url1, obj1).pipe(map((res:Response) => res)),
      this.http.post(url2, obj2).pipe(map((res:Response) => res))
  ).subscribe(
    data => {

      console.log('Data Called');

    },
    error => {

      console.log('Error Called');


    });
```

**NodeJS code:**

```
res.status(401).send({ error: "error", message: "Oops! Please try again" });
res.end();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you want to call things sequentially you should not use `forkJoin` it will fire all request at one and then wait for all of them to complete. If you want to invoke them one by one use `concat`

```
import { concat } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs';    

//emits 1,2,3
const sourceOne = of(1, 2, 3);
//emits 4,5,6
const sourceTwo = of(4, 5, 6);

//used as static
const example = concat(sourceOne, sourceTwo);
```

But aside from that. Your question is why the error method is not triggered. And that is because the observer chain is destroyed the moment the error is thrown somewhere in the middle of processing. If you want to protect yourself from this you have to cache it either on the problematic observable.

```
forkJoin(
      this.http.post(url1, obj1).pipe(map((res:Response) => res)).pipe(catchError(val => of('I caught: ${val}'))),
      this.http.post(url2, obj2).pipe(map((res:Response) => res)).pipe(catchError(val => of('I caught: ${val}')))
  ).subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log('Data Called');
    },
    error => {
      console.log('Error Called');
    });
```

Or the second option is to cache it. But then you get nothing if one of the observables throw an error.

```
forkJoin(
          this.http.post(url1, obj1).pipe(map((res:Response) => res)),
          this.http.post(url2, obj2).pipe(map((res:Response) => res))
      )
.pipe(catchError(val => of('I caught: ${val}')))
.subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log('Data Called');
        },
        error => {
          console.log('Error Called');
        });
```

The documentation clearly states as much:
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html